# Is Microsoft Cognitive Translator service "pt" language certified to be Brazilian Portugese?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have recently started using Microsoft Cognitive Services for translations, and the Translator does support the "pt" language. I ran a few tests with 'reception, train, bus, cream, brown' and got the Brazilian Portuguese translations. I would have expected to get the Portuguese ones with this language code and the need to use pt-br for the Brazilian version.

As what I need the most is the Brazilian language, this is not an issue, but I would like to make sure the behavior won't change further down the line, or that my test was indeed good enough.

Is there anyway to confirm that the "pt" language code used as a destination language is indeed and will always result in Brazilian Portuguese translations ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following is a response from a Cognitive Service Engineer:

Our Translation engines are not locale specific. So we have one for EN (US, AUS, UK, etc.) , one for FR, one for ES, and one for PT.

That being said, most of our training data for PT is Brazilian Portuguese so most likely all translations will be PT-BR more than PT-PT.

Finally, for speech translation (the API and the product it supports: Microsoft Translator live , Skype Translator), our ASR was only trained on BR speech data.